# Sherlock and Cost on Hackerrank

Tags: recursion, dynamic-programming

It's about [this](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/sherlock-and-cost/problem) **dynamic programming** challenge.

If you have a hard time to understand the Problem then see also on **AbhishekVermaIIT**'s [post](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/sherlock-and-cost/forum/comments/228472)

Basically, you get as input an array B and you construct array A. Fo this array A you need the **maximum possible sum** with `absolute(A[i] - A[i-1])`, for `i = 1 to N`. How to construct array A? --> You can choose for every element `A[i]` in array `A` either the values `1` or `B[i]`. (As you will deduce from the problem description any other value between these two values doesn't make any sense.)

And I came up with this recursive Java solution (without memoization):

```
static int costHelper(int[] arr, int i) {
  if (i < 1) return 0;

  int q = max(abs(1 - arr[i-1]) + costHelper(arr, i-1) , abs(arr[i] - arr[i-1]) + costHelper(arr, i-1));

  int[] arr1 = new int[i];
  for (int j = 0; j < arr1.length-1; j++) {
    arr1[j] = arr[j];
  }
  arr1[i-1] = 1;
  int r = max(abs(1 - 1) + costHelper(arr1, i-1) , abs(arr[i] - 1) + costHelper(arr1, i-1));

  return max(q , r);
}


static int cost(int[] arr) {
  return costHelper(arr, arr.length-1);
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
  int[] arr = {55, 68, 31, 80, 57, 18, 34, 28, 76, 55};
  int result = cost(arr);
  System.out.println(result);
}
```

Basically, I start at the end of the array and check what is maximizing the sum of the `last element` minus `last element - 1`. But I have 4 cases:

1. `(1 - arr[i-1])`
2. `(arr[i] - arr[i-1])`
3. `(1 - 1) // I know, it is not necessary.`
4. `(arr[i] -1)`

For the 3rd or 4th case I construct a new array one element smaller in size than the input array and with a `1` as the last element.

Now, the result of `arr = 55 68 31 80 57 18 34 28 76 55` according to Hackerrank should be 508. But I get 564.

Since it has to be 508 I guess the array should be `1 68 1 80 1 1 34 1 76 1`.

For other arrays I get the right answer. For example:

```
79 6 40 68 68 16 40 63 93 49 91 --> 642 (OK)

100 2 100 2 100 --> 396 (OK)
```

I don't understand what is wrong with this algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure exactly what's happening with your particular solution but I suspect it might be that the recursive function only has one dimension, `i`, since we need a way to identify the best previous solution, `f(i-1)`, both if `B_(i-1)` was chosen and if `1` was chosen at that point, so we can choose the best among them vis-a-vis `f(i)`. (It might help if you could add a description of your algorithm in words.)

Let's look at the brute-force dynamic program: let `m[i][j1]` represent the best sum-of-abs-diff in `A[0..i]` when `A_i` is `j1`. Then, generally:

```
m[i][j1] = max(abs(j1 - j0) + m[i-1][j0])
  for j0 in [1..B_(i-1)] and j1 in [1..B_i]
```

Python code:

```py
def cost(arr):
  if len(arr) == 1:
    return 0

  m = [[float('-inf')]*101 for i in xrange(len(arr))]

  for i in xrange(1, len(arr)):
    for j0 in xrange(1, arr[i-1] + 1):
      for j1 in xrange(1, arr[i] + 1):
        m[i][j1] = max(m[i][j1], abs(j1 - j0) + (m[i-1][j0] if i > 1 else 0))

  return max(m[len(arr) - 1])
```

That works but times out since we are looping potentially 100*100*10^5 iterations.

I haven't thought through the proof for it, but, as you suggest, apparently we can choose only from either `1` or `B_i` for each `A_i` for an optimal solution. This allows us to choose between those directly in a significantly more efficient solution that won't time out:

```py
def cost(arr):
  if len(arr) == 1:
    return 0

  m = [[float('-inf')]*2 for i in xrange(len(arr))]

  for i in xrange(1, len(arr)):
    for j0 in [1, arr[i-1]]:
      for j1 in [1, arr[i]]:
        a_i = 0 if j1 == 1 else 1
        b_i = 0 if j0 == 1 else 1

        m[i][a_i] = max(m[i][a_i], abs(j1 - j0) + (m[i-1][b_i] if i > 1 else 0))

  return max(m[len(arr) - 1])
```

This is a bottom-up tabulation but we could easily convert it to a recursive one using the same idea.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the javascript code with memoization-

```
function cost(B,n,val) {
    if(n==-1){
        return 0;
    }
    let prev1=0,prev2=0;
    if(n!=0){
        if(dp[n-1][0]==-1)
            dp[n-1][0] = cost(B,n-1,1);        
        if(dp[n-1][1]==-1)
            dp[n-1][1] = cost(B,n-1,B[n]);
        prev1=dp[n-1][0];
        prev2=dp[n-1][1];
    }
    prev1 = prev1 + Math.abs(val-1);
    prev2 = prev2+ Math.abs(val-B[n]);
    return Math.max(prev1,prev2);
}
```

where B->given array,n->total length,val-> 1 or B[n], value considered by the calling function.

Initial call -> Math.max(cost(B,n-2,1),cost(B,n-2,B[n-1]));

BTW, this took me around 3hrs, rather could have easily done with iteration method. :p

Answer (score 0):

```
           //dp[][0] is when a[i]=b[i]
       dp[i][0]=max((dp[i-1][0]+abs(b[i]-b[i-1])),(dp[i-1][1]+abs(b[i]-1)));
       dp[i][1]=max((dp[i-1][1]+abs(1-1)),(dp[i-1][0]+abs(b[i-1]-1)));
```

Initially all the elements in dp have the value of 0.
We know that we will get the answer if at any i the value is b[i] or 1. So the final answer is :

```
max(dp[n-1][0],dp[n-1][1])
```

dp[i][0] signifies a[i]=b[i] and dp[i][1] signifies a[i]=1.
So at every i we want the maximum of [i-1][0] (previous element is b[i-1]) or [i-1][1] (previous element is 1)